# Code gives type error File.update is not a function

Tags: node.js, mongodb, updates

I'm trying to update a field in a set of mongodb docs, but I'm running into this error and can't figure out what's causing it.

```
import mongoose from 'mongoose';
import File from './models/File';
const app = express();
const router = express.Router();

router.route('/files/addids').post((req, res)=>{
   File.find().stream()
   .on('data',function(File){
    File.update({_id:File._id}, {
        $set: {
            fileID: File.fileName.slice(-10),
        }})
    .on('error',function(err){
        res.status(400).send('Failed to update'); 
    })
    .on('end',function(){
        res.status(200).json({'File':'Updated'});
    })
   })

});
```

Comment: Whats the error

Comment: "Type Error: File.update is not a function"

Answer (score 0):

Take this as an example and to know more check this page https://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#model_Model.update if you are on mongoose V5.7.3

```
var query = { name: 'borne' };
Model.update(query, { name: 'jason bourne' }, options, callback);

// is sent as
Model.update(query, { $set: { name: 'jason bourne' }}, options, function(err, res));
// if overwrite option is false. If overwrite is true, sent without the $set wrapper.
```

You can add and remove fields in schema using option `{ strict: false }`

**option: strict**

> The strict option, (enabled by default), ensures that values passed to
>   our model constructor that were not specified in our schema do not get
>   saved to the db.

```
var thingSchema = new Schema({..}, { strict: false });
```

And also you can do this in update query as well

```
Model.findOneAndUpdate(
  query,  //filter
  update, //data to update
  { //options
    returnNewDocument: true,
    new: true,
    strict: false
  }
)
```

You can check the documentations [here](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/guide.html)

Comment: The original code may have made this a bit confusing, but I'm not trying to rename any actual files, or do anything with any files. File is just the name of the database I'm working with, which contains data which isn't related to any actual file path ( I know, it's a terrible name, I apologise). I have documents in this "file" database that I want to add a field to, "fileID", based on the pre-existing field "file Name". I don't understand how using filestream would let me do that, unless I'm just misunderstanding your code.

Comment: I updated my answer. Upvote if you find this helpfull

Answer (score 0):

I think, it should look like this.

```
import mongoose from 'mongoose';
import File from './models/File';
const app = express();
const router = express.Router();

router.route('/files/addids').post((req, res)=>{
   File.find().stream()
   .on('data',function(file){
    File.update({_id:file._id}, {
        $set: {
            fileID: file.fileName.slice(-10),
        }})
    .on('error',function(err){
        res.status(400).send('Failed to update'); 
    })
    .on('end',function(){
        res.status(200).json({'File':'Updated'});
    })
   })

});
```